# JaxB API understanding

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb

I want to create the Model classes by using XSD. I have tried with the jaxbthrough eclipse. But I want to generate POJO classes through java code by using JAXB API. I have googled it. got the jars of jaxb-api-2.2. But not getting how to use it. Can any one having a sample example or link so that i can quickly go through and start the work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you question right, to generate classes in Eclipse using JAXB API you need to download your XML Schema (XSD), for example to root directory of your JAXB project, right-click on it and choose Generate -> JAXB Classes

Comment: Yes Thats ok, But I am looking for the java API(Classes and Methods) of JAXB by which i can create the POJOs though java code.